# To generate input according to the selected property of any model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I list the viewmodel properties on the page as drop-down properties. I want to generate input depending on the property type. (text, radio, numbering, etc.).  I want to do this dynamically with partialViews. Can you give me an idea of ​​how I can do it?

```
<select class="form-control no-multiselect" id="filterSelect" name="@nameof(Model)" onchange="loadPartial()">
        <option value="">Please Selected</option>
        @foreach (var item in Model.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            <option value="@item.Name" compulsory="@(item.CustomAttributes.Any(x => x.AttributeType.Name == "RequiredAttribute") == true ? "true" :"false")"  type="@item.PropertyType.Name">@item.Name</option>
        }
    </select>

 $("#filterSelect").on("change",
                function() {

                    var name = $("#filterSelect").val();
                    var type = $('option:selected', this).attr('type');
                    var compulsory = $('option:selected', this).attr('compulsory');

                    $(this).find('option:selected').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                    var div = document.getElementById('share');

                    var label = document.createElement("label"); 
                    var text = document.createTextNode(name); 
                    label.appendChild(text);

                    if (type === "String") {

                        var input1 = document.createElement('input');
                        input1.setAttribute('type', 'text');
                        input1.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
                        input1.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Name');
                        input1.setAttribute('name', 'routename');
                        input1.setAttribute('id', name);

                        if (compulsory === "true"){
                            input1.setAttribute('required', true);
                        }

                        div.appendChild(label);
                        div.appendChild(input1);
                    }

                    if (type === "Boolean") {
                        var select = document.createElement('select');
                        select.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');

                        if (compulsory === "true") {
                            select.setAttribute('required', true);
                        }

                        var Item = new Option("True", true);
                        select.options[select.length] = Item;

                        var Item2 = new Option("False", false);
                        select.options[select.length] = Item2;

                        div.appendChild(label);
                        div.appendChild(select);
                    }
                });
```

So when I select from dropdown, I want it to be  if the property is text. Also, if this property is an enum, I want to list the enum's list as dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same approach as your `type` attribute.

You can use [`IsEnum()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isenum?view=netcore-3.0) to check if the type is an Enum and [`Enum.GetNames(type)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getnames?view=netcore-3.0#System_Enum_GetNames_System_Type_) to get available value names for that Enum.

```
<option   
 data-options="@item.PropertyType.IsEnum() ? string.Join(',',Enum.GetNames(item.PropertyType)):''">@item.Name</option>
  >@item.Name</option>
```

In your javascript, you can check the value of `data-options` attribute and decide to show a `<select>`.

My razor syntax may have errors. Check and make sure it works.